# Gitlab unicorn webserver either does not listen or reply on 8080

Tags: ruby, webserver, unicorn, gitlab

GitLab can be started and shows as running. When running curl git.myserver.com, this fails with HTTP 503. No interesting entries in the unicorn.stderr.log or unicorn.stdout.log.

Versions:

- GitLab 6.5.1
- Apache 2.4.6
- Ubuntu 13.10

sites-available/git.myserver.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.myserver.com

  DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public

  <Directory /home/git/gitlab/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  ProxyPass /uploads !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

config/unicorn.rb:

```ruby
worker_processes 2
listen "/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket", :backlog => 64
listen "127.0.0.1:8080", :tcp_nopush => true
timeout 900
```

config/gitlab.yml:

```yml
gitlab:
  ## Web server settings
  host: git.myserver.com
  port: 80
  https: false
```

Apache access log file:

```
SOMEIPADDRESS - - [17/Feb/2014:20:25:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 566 "-" "curl/7.32.0"
```

Apache error log file:

```
[Mon Feb 17 20:25:08.919614 2014] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1321:tid 139972136904448] [client SOMEIPADDRESS:48578] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Mon Feb 17 20:25:20.114281 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 2092:tid 140263968208640] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Mon Feb 17 20:25:20.114353 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 2092:tid 140263968208640] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s
[Mon Feb 17 20:25:20.114364 2014] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2092:tid 140263968208640] [client SOMEIPADDRESS:48580] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Does you apache runs as `root`?

Comment: root@git:~# ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
    root      2091  0.0  0.1  79812  2844 ?        Ss   20:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data  2092  0.0  0.1 434600  3168 ?        Sl   20:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    www-data  2093  0.0  0.1 434592  3100 ?        Sl   20:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs?

Comment: @UriAgassi Added Apache log extracts to post.

Comment: Can you access gitlab directly? So tying to access it e.g. with curl to localhost:8080. Is the service really started and listening on the port you like to? Check with `netstat -tulpn`

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had used Ruby 2.1.0 while the install guide tells to use Ruby 2.0.0. Closely re-installed and restored the backup, which now works perfectly.